# ImageList size [500x500] in Windows-form application

Tags: winforms, imagelist

How can I set the ImageList size to the dimensions: [500x500] in a Windows-form application?

Please help me, and thank you in advance.

Comment: ImageList1.ImageSize = new Size(500,500);

Comment: Sry but imagelist greater size is 256

Comment: thank you, but we can't assign imagelist size greater then 256..

Comment: ImageList is limited to 256x256, you better use a Collection like an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

ImageList size is 256x256.

Alternatively you can use List imageList1;

If you need to store key like ImageList, you can use "tag" parameters of List.